# how to trigger build.xml file of particular directory if there is any checkin inside that directory with perforce?

Tags: version-control, perforce, polling, perforce-stream

There are 5 modules inside a branch in perforce and each module have many directories with java files and build.xml files, how should i trigger particular build.xml file if there is checkin inside that directory

ex:Below is the sample structure, if there is any checkin in cord9aif build.xml file inside that should be triggered.

AMX->oms->bb->cord9aif->jjpj.java,build.xml
              bbbbbbb-> kkhfdh->hgkjgh.java,build.xml
              test

Answer (score 0):

A really easy way is to set up a commit trigger on the Perforce server:

```
change-commit //AMX/oms/bb/cord9aif/... "perl run-my-build.pl"
```

This has the benefit of automatically happening the instant a change is committed to that directory, but it depends on you having infrastructure set up where a script that's run on your server can trigger a build (presumably on some other machine).

If you don't have access to the Perforce server, or the Perforce server doesn't have access to where the build needs to happen, or both, you can do it by polling from any client machine (e.g. your build machine which I'd assume is set up as a Perforce client).

The way I'd probably do it would be to have a job that runs `p4 sync` on the affected directory and looks at the output:

1. Any errors or otherwise unexpected output?  Page a human.
2. Any files updated?  Kick off a build.
3. Otherwise, do nothing.

Another option would be to run `p4 changes` against that directory and keep track of the most recently seen change -- whenever there's a new change, tell your build machine to `p4 sync` and kick off the build.